# How to use last query from db and arrange it in form of an answer?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have 2 columns, left and right with 10 buttons in each. Now I setText to each buttons with terms from imported database in assets folder, and shuffle them. And user needs to connect correct terms (first and last name for example). Anyway, that works fine. Here's my question: how to, when game ends, present correct answers...how to arrange text to buttons so buttons A1 and B1 are one pair, A2 and B2 are the second pair and so on? I hope you understand me...the game ended, user get some correct answers and some not, and now I need to show him all correct answers. I have columns in my database like this: _ID, QUESTION, A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3.....A10, B10. Here's my code for setting the question and terms to my buttons (I've deleted some code and placed dots instead):

```
public void nextQuestion() {


        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        if(!myDbHelper.checkDataBase()){
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        }

        try{ 

            mDbHelper.open();

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getSpojnice(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsA = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsB = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();

            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(2), "1"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(3), "1"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(4), "2"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(5), "2"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(6), "3"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(7), "3"));
          .
          .
          .
          .


            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

            pitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).label);
            a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0).tag);
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0).label);
            b1.setTag(labelsB.get(0).tag);
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1).label);
            a2.setTag(labelsA.get(1).tag);
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1).label);
            b2.setTag(labelsB.get(1).tag);
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a3.setText(labelsA.get(2).label);
            a3.setTag(labelsA.get(2).tag);
            a3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b3.setText(labelsB.get(2).label);
            b3.setTag(labelsB.get(2).tag);
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
          .
          .
          .
          .
          .
            }
        }


        finally{
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself. I've made String variable and in the same moment I get data from my sqlite database I use it in my code and store it in my String variables. After the game end I simply use the data in variable to present it as correct result. Just in case someone else needs something like this.

```
String str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, str7, str8, str9, str10, str11, str12, str13, str14, str15, str16;

str1 = c.getString(2);
            str9 = c.getString(3);
            str2 = c.getString(4);
            str10 = c.getString(5);
            str3 = c.getString(6);
            str11 = c.getString(7);
            str4 = c.getString(8);
            str12 = c.getString(9);
            str5 = c.getString(10);
            str13 = c.getString(11);
            str6 = c.getString(12);
            str14 = c.getString(13);
            str7 = c.getString(14);
            str15 = c.getString(15);
            str8 = c.getString(16);
            str16 = c.getString(17);
```